# How do I find the IP address of the server I am playing on?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm looking for the IP address of the server I play on. Because when you write down the server's IP address you can get back in that lobby.

Answer (score 0):

When in the multiplayer menu, select a server. Then, click "Edit." This will pull up the IP address that you use to connect to the server.